# Want to pass data to next page in PHP code igniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
$(".content-wrapper").on("click",".modalButton", function(e) {  
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url()."stock_details/edit";?>",
        method: "post", 
        data : {
        id: $(this).attr("data-src")
        }
        }).done(function(data) {
        $(location).attr('href', '<?php echo base_url()."stock_details/edit";?>').html(data);

    })
});
```

This code is for edit the table data
I just pass the current row id and retrive data then I want to pass the data to the edit page here I met the problem

Comment: I don't get the point why you would want to first POST data to the edit page and then go there when finished? Why not just linking to the page direcly without the ajax call?

Comment: I think we're lost in translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do only request the edit page with the `$(location).attr('href',URL)` call, you do not post any data. I would recommend you to send the ID as a GET parameter instead, change the line to:

```
$(location).attr('href', '<?php echo base_url(); ?>stock_details/edit?id='+$(this).attr("data-src"));
```

OR, even more CI-like, send it to the controller as a parameter:

```
$(location).attr('href', '<?php echo base_url(); ?>stock_details/edit/'+$(this).attr("data-src"));
```

Then in the controller/model for the edit page add possibility to use both POST and GET the `id` value.